# Discuss from the source whether SpringApplication's run method will be executed twice

Tags: spring-boot

I looked at the source of springboot, and I felt that the run method of SpringApplication would be executed twice.
The first time, when you execute the following code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(HppaApplication.class, args);
}
```

The second time, Servlet3.0 when specified in the web container startup time will go to the callback ServletContainerInitializer onStartup method in the implementation class, and through the @ HandlesTypes into corresponding implementation classes, and finally in the call to SpringBootServletInitializer onStartup method, this method calls the createRootApplicationContext method,CreateRootApplicationContext method in the code below

```
protected WebApplicationContext createRootApplicationContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
    // Omit other code
    return run(application);
}
```

Again, SpringApplication's run method is executed.
Why execute this method twice?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't called twice. The main method is only used when running as a standalone application. The call via `SpringBootServletInitializer` is only used when deployed to a servlet container.